# Change detection and the necessity of being applied to all the components

Tags: angular

I am studying Angular's change detection and I came across the following query: Let's take as base the following code:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <h1>{{item}}</h1>
    <button (click)="changeModel()">Change</button>
  `
})
class MyApp {

  item:string = 'cheese';

  changeModel() {
    this.item = 'bread';
  }
}
```

Once we click `Change` button, our ***model changes***, ***change detection is triggered*** and the appropriate DOM updates will be applied as to reflect the change in `item`. So far so good. However, Angular triggers change detection to all the components. *So, here is my query*: What's the point in doing that? Let's say, there is another component **B** which has a binding with `item.` When sometime in the future, **B** is about to be shown, the new DOM will be built upon the new correct value of `item`. So once again, `what's the point in running change detection in B` every time the value of `item` is changed through the above presented component?

Comment: How else should Angular decide, which parts of the DOM need to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So once again, what's the point in running change detection in B every
>   time the value of item is changed through the above presented
>   component?

Let's assume you **B component** is child of **MyApp component**. `Item` is bound to **B component** via @Input. So:

```
class BComponent{
 @Input() item: string;

 ngOnChanges(changeObj){
  // catch item changes here

 }

}
```

Every time when value of `Item` is changes in **Parent** component, `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook of B component is called accordingly.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h16d2s)

> So, what's the use of applying change detection in C component when
>   something changes in A?

In Angular change detection strategy works from top component to their childs.
Any components of angular will be direct/indirect child **Root component**. So, root component is starting point. If you have some tree of components in UI, you can disable change detection **with some exceptions** on components and their childs accodrdingly:
[image]

Just apply to component decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

If you want to read about more deeply, there are great articles from Max NgWizard K. @AngularInDepth.com

[Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** : *Angular checks for changes everywhere at each player interaction because it's the easiest and most reliable way to handle interactions, by using services you could have a component impact another while they're only linked by a service handling data, the `Default` change detector strategy acts like that but there's other solutions.*

The default change detector strategy is basically like saying "If anything happens anywhere in the app, check every other elements to make sure there's no changes, else apply the changes". This is nice for small apps but once you start to have a lot of components with badly optimized calls (like heavy computing function calls in template) it becomes really heavy and slow.

I guess your question behind this is "How to change this behavior?".

Change detector can be affected by multiple ways:

#### [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)

The first way of changing that is by setting the  `changeDetectionStrategy` property in your `@Component` decorator parameter object to `OnPush`, this is like saying to the change detector "Only consider this component and its children as changed if one of the inputs changed.".

#### Detaching [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

You can inject the change detector ref anywhere by simply adding it to your component contructor function (`private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef`), once you injected this, you have full control over the change detector for the current component and its children, you can detach it, which is like saying "Don't check changes here" and reattach it when you want, you can also manually tell the CD to check changes, and apply them to the DOM.